# Overbraces in Excel

Tags: excel

From Googling I've only found "regular" braces, i.e. `}` in varying sizes. I want to achieve an overbrace spanning some columns in a table. I only want the [overbrace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12963/how-to-have-overlapping-under-braces-and-over-braces) (where the brace "starting first" is an overbrace, and the latter an underbrace) and the `x` over it in the example is not needed.

Is there a way to achieve an overbrace  in Excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) but I am not sure I understand the requirement since you say you know abut "regular" braces. If you would like something like this:

[image: SO30841326 first example]

show first with and lower down without the `x`, it may be achieved with insertion of a shape object: INSERT > Illustrations - Shapes, Right Brace in the case of Excel 2013.

Then rotating, stretching and moving the shape to suit, the handles for which are shown:

[image: SO30841326 second example]

and colour adjusted with Shape Outline.